# Set of homomorphisms between vector spaces notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

$V$, $W$ are vector spaces, $K$ is a field.

This may sounds like a very silly question, but I have seen the notation

$$\mathrm{Hom}_K(V,W)$$

which presumably denotes the set of homomorphisms i.e. linear maps between vector spaces. (I’ve only previously seen it written with different notation)

A linear map i.e. homomorphism of vector spaces $f: V \to W$ requires them to be over the same field $K$, so presumably we can also drop the $K$ and write

$$\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$$

with the first example’s use of $K$ only there for clarity rather than having any different meaning to the second one. Am I correct?

Comment: The index may however become important if you jump between different fields. E.g., if $V$ and $W$ are spaces over $\mathbb C$, then they are also spaces over $\mathbb R$, and you may write something like $\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb R}(V,W)=4\cdot\dim \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(V,W)$. -- Alternatively, one might introduce some notation that differentiates between "$V$ as $\mathbb C$-space" from "$V$, but we now consider it as $\mathbb R$-space"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ah, yes, that makes sense. If we were to previously specify the field and only ever work over one field it would presumably be okay, though?

Comment: Sure, that would be fine. (But it is not always a good idea to constantly change notation; so people who encounter different fields frequently will often prefer writing down the field even in single-field contexts.)